# What is the purpose of an abstract METHOD in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
// A convenient function that can be used for any abstract method
function abstractmethod() { throw new Error("abstract method"); }

// The AbstractSet class defines a single abstract method, contains().
function AbstractSet() { throw new Error("Can't instantiate abstract classes");}
AbstractSet.prototype.contains = abstractmethod;
```

From "Javascript: The Definitive Guide - 9.7.4 Class Hierarchies and Abstract Classes"
I understand the utility of abstract classes in JavaScript. What I don't understand is the necessity or use of setting abstract methods that only throw an error.  You can't create an instance of that class, so only instances of the subclasses will exist. They'll each have their own definition for these methods, so why establish an inheritance to a method that just throws a generic error?

Thank you in advance for your guiding response.

Comment: They're "abstract" precisely *because* they throw an error. It's a mechanism to prevent unintended use of the abstract base classes, no?

Comment: yes, which would explain the 'throw' in the constructor.  im confused about the creation of the prototype method that does nothing but throw an error as well.  seems to me, if the contains() method only serves to throw an error here, why not wait to define it in the first subclass (abstract or concrete) that actually will define it more completely?

Comment: Why wait to define it? It's the abstract/base class that defines the "contract" that subclasses should follow. Classes that implement it will override it, removing the exception. Classes that don't (abstract subclasses) can just rely on its parent class to provide the exception.

Comment: okay, so this is merely a common practice for readability purposes... serves no other purpose but to provide warning when/if a concrete subclass is incomplete? (rabinowitz's answer)

Comment: Yes--there's no such thing as an "abstract class" in JavaScript (no such thing as "class" either, but different issue) so you have to indicate implementation errors and functionality in other ways.

Comment: Abstract classes, by definition, implement a non-working shell that subclasses must fill in the functionality for by overriding the methods to actually do useful things.  That's what an abstract class is.  The word "abstract" means that it doesn't do anything by itself until it's sub-classed and real functionality is added.

Comment: Meh, semantics. there's no formal 'class'. There is a 'group of objects classified by common inheritance.'  Thanks for the help though, i believe i've got it

Comment: @jfriend - i must have oddly worded my question, lol,  i understand an abstract class, just didnt see the point in an abstract method.

Comment: @Marlin - OK, the behavior of an abstract class is defined by it's methods - so it usually needs methods, even if they're placeholders to show the behavior that it is representing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the purpose of this is that it's not a generic error - it's an error that informs you where you went wrong (i.e. you failed to override the method in a subclass). If you didn't define that method, you would get an error saying "Undefined is not a function" (or something similar) and you'd have to spend time hunting around your code to understand why - this way it fails in a more verbose and useful manner.

The other reason, I'd assume, is to indicate the class interface to downstream developers implementing subclasses. Javascript doesn't have any kind of formal interface declaration, so it's helpful to be able to inspect the abstract class and see what methods I'm expected to implement.

Comment: seems plausible, but i'm hesitant because the first concrete class formed from this abstract class contains methods not initialized in its 'parent'

Comment: @Marlin: there's no problem with a child class having methods not in its parent (regardless of whether the parent is abstract). You only have a problem if the child concrete class doesn't implement methods that are defined in the parent as abstract. (In languages like Java a concrete class that doesn't implement all of the parent(s)' abstract methods wouldn't even compile, but in JavaScript you'll get the runtime error thrown in the code you show only if something tries to call the 'missing' method.)